# RowSelected not being called in UITableViewSource

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have been trying to implement a multi column table view by combining multiple UITableViews.

One problem I have run into, is that I am unable to get the override of RowSelected to be called when I select a row on one of the TableViews in my multi column view.

When running in the simulator, It highlights a row when clicked, so the ability to click a row is working, however the override is not called.

Below is the code for the UITableViewSource. Under that is the code that sets up the multi column view.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class TableSource : UITableViewSource 
{
    protected List<object> _tableItems;
    protected string cellIdentifier = "TableCell";
    private string _propertyName;
    public TableSource (List<object> items, string propertyName)
    {
        _tableItems = items;
        _propertyName = propertyName;
    }
    public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section)
    {
        return _tableItems.Count;
    }
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        // request a recycled cell to save memory
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier);
        // if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
        if (cell == null)
            cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIdentifier);
        PropertyInfo property = _tableItems [indexPath.Row].GetType ().GetProperty (_propertyName);
        cell.TextLabel.Text = property.GetValue(_tableItems[indexPath.Row]).ToString();
        cell.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
        return cell;
    }

    public override UIView GetViewForHeader (UITableView tableView, int section)
    {
        // NOTE: Don't call the base implementation on a Model class
        // see http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/delegates,_protocols,_and_events
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }

    public override void RowDeselected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        // NOTE: Don't call the base implementation on a Model class
        // see http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/delegates,_protocols,_and_events
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }

    public override void RowHighlighted (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath rowIndexPath)
    {
        // NOTE: Don't call the base implementation on a Model class
        // see http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/delegates,_protocols,_and_events
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }
    public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        new UIAlertView("Row Selected", "", null, "OK", null).Show();
        tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true);
    }
}






[Register("MultiColumnTableView")]
public class MultiColumnTableView: UIView
{
    List<SingleColumnView> _tableViews;
    IEnumerable<object> _dataSource;
    SingleColumnView scrollingTable = null;
    int _nextColumnX;

    public MultiColumnTableView(){
    }
    public MultiColumnTableView (IntPtr handle):base(handle)
    {

    }

    public IEnumerable<object> DataSource
    {
        get 
        {
            return _dataSource;
        }
        set 
        {
            _dataSource = value;
        }
    }

    public void AddColumn(string columnName, string propertyName, int width)
    {
        if(_tableViews== null)
            _tableViews = new List<SingleColumnView>();
        var newColumn = new SingleColumnView (columnName, propertyName, _dataSource, width, _nextColumnX);
        this.AddSubview (newColumn);
        _tableViews.Add (newColumn);
        _nextColumnX += (width);
        newColumn.Scrolled += Scrolled;
        foreach(var table in _tableViews)
        {
            table.ShowsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;
        }
        _tableViews.Last ().ShowsVerticalScrollIndicator = true;
    }

    public void AddColumn(string columnName, string[] propertyNames, string format)
    {
        if(_tableViews== null)
            _tableViews = new List<SingleColumnView>();
        var column = new SingleColumnView (columnName, propertyNames, format, _dataSource);
        _tableViews.Add (column);
        column.Scrolled += Scrolled;
        foreach(var table in _tableViews)
        {
            table.ShowsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;
            table.AllowsSelection = true;
        }
        _tableViews.Last ().ShowsVerticalScrollIndicator = true;
    }

    private void Scrolled (object sender, EventArgs args) 
    {
        if (scrollingTable == null) {
            scrollingTable = sender as SingleColumnView;
        }
        if(scrollingTable != _tableViews.Last())
            _tableViews.Last().FlashScrollIndicators();
        foreach (var table in _tableViews) {
            if (table != sender) {
                table.ContentOffset = (sender as SingleColumnView).ContentOffset;
            }
        }
        scrollingTable = null;
    }
}

public class SingleColumnView: UITableView
{
    public IEnumerable<object> _dataSource;
    public string _propertyName;
    public string[] _propertyNames;
    public string _format;
    public string _columnName;

    public SingleColumnView(string columnName, string propertyName, IEnumerable<object> dataSource, int width, int offsetX):base(new RectangleF(offsetX,0,width,500))
    {
        _columnName = columnName;
        _propertyName = propertyName;
        _dataSource = dataSource;
        this.Source = new TableSource (dataSource.ToList(), propertyName);
        //this.BackgroundColor = new UIColor(new MonoTouch.CoreGraphics.CGColor(255,0,0));
        //this.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
        this.SeparatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.Zero;
    }

    public SingleColumnView(string columnName, string[] propertyNames, string format, IEnumerable<object> dataSource):base()
    {
        _columnName = columnName;
        _propertyNames = propertyNames;
        _format = format;
        _dataSource = dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: declared your delegates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you implementing the custom UITableViewDelegate? I would suggest using Monotouch's UITableViewSource as it combines both the UITableViewDataSource and the UITableViewDelegate into one file which makes things so much easier.

Source:[more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549289/monotouch-uitableviewdelegate-rowselected-event-cannot-be-used)

Add to You project

I think you should try using `WeakDelegate` to make this work.

Comment: where do I add this, I am writing the app in monotouch (c#)

Comment: thanks, however if you see my code above, I have already implemented UITableViewSource